# How does one calculate product pricing to cover processing fees from $\$5$ to $\$5,000$ while maintaining a profit?

Tags: finance

Credit card processor charges, for each transaction, $2.9\% + \$0.30$.

I need to find an amount that covers that cost, from $\$5$ to $\$5,000$, on a per item basis, all while maintaining a small profit.

For example, a customer may want to purchase 3 items. Each item has a different price and possibly a different fee structure based on whether or not it's a for-profit purchase or non-profit purchase.

Item 1 is $\$10$ and for-profit so we need to account for the processing fee plus a $5\%$ profit.

Item 2 is $\$80$ and for-profit so we need to account for the processing fee plus a $5\%$ profit.

Item 3 is $\$25$ and non-profit so we need to account for the processing fee only- no profit.

What I cannot determine is a full-proof way to account for the fees all the way up to $5,000 without losing money on the processing fees.

Comment: You have used the dollar sign. It has confused the mathjax interpreter. Please use something else like £.

Comment: @jasonsfa98: Welcome to MSE! There is still a problem with the dollar signs. Also, do you have thought on the problem and can share what you have tried as it helps responders? Regards

Comment: I've set things inside MathJax with backslashes in front of the dollar signs and percent signs that are supposed to actually appear.  The same thing works in standard LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

I will ignore dollar signs. Suppose that $C$ is the cost of the product and we wish to charge $C + X$ for the product. The processing fee is $.029(C + X) + .3$.
We need to solve
$$(C + X) - (.029(C + X) + .3) \geq C$$
for $X$. In this equation $C + X$ is what we charge and $.029(C + X) + .3$ is the processing fee. If the difference is greater than $C$ we make a profit. There are probably other costs that are not mentioned in this problem. Presumably they are included in the value of $C$. In any event we need
$$.971 X \geq .029 C + .3.$$
We can solve for $X$ as follows:
$$X \geq \frac{.029 C + .3}{.971}.$$
There is no upper bound for the value of $X$.